# Blackberry - how to count unread sms messages?

Tags: blackberry, integration, sms

Can anyone please help me .... I need the full code.
Folder containing inbox ... and i need to count the unread sms there.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it's not possible.

[How to Read SMS inbox (Not for mail messages)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=54343):

> This is not possible under the current api, you can access them before they hit the sms >inbox but you cant read back into the inbox
>   ...
>   There is no way to access SMS once they hit the inbox.

[Access all SMS in my inbox through API](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/143681-access-all-sms-my-inbox-through-api.html):

> sms: no
>   mails: yes. take a look at the developer guide for details
>   ...
>   you can not access any stored sms programatically.
>   you can intercept incoming sms, but that's it.
>   it is possible to read them from a backup file on your pc though.

[Accessing SMS folders viz Inbox,Drafts etc](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=1150&query.id=2271#M1150):

> This is not supported on BlackBerry. You can capture messages as they arrive, but can not >access SMS messages stored on the BlackBerry.
>
> Mark Sohm
>   BlackBerry Development Advisor
>   www.BlackBerryDeveloper.com
>   ...
>   It is not possible to programmatically access SMS folders. SMS messages can only be >captured as they arrive.
>
> Mark Sohm
>   BlackBerry Development Advisor
>   www.BlackBerryDeveloper.com

All we can do is [handle incoming SMS](http://myhowto.org/java/j2me/22-sending-and-receiving-gsm-sms-on-blackberry-using-rim-apis/#blackberry_way_in)

Comment: Is not tagging this question with RIM-4.2 somewhat misleading? The OP asked specifically about 4.2, but isn't the answer is true for all known versions of the API?